# Problem with biblatex and footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I'm currently writing a research paper and want to manage my bibliography with biblatex. Everything is working fine except a minor annoyance:

Whenever I use the `\footfullcite[pagenumber]{key}` command there is no space between the full citation and the page number in the postnote.

I uploaded a minimal example [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16646915/example.zip)

Is there any way to solve this?

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: Here's a boiled-down example that still shows the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{test,
  title = {The Infamous Test},
  publisher = {Testington Test},
  year = {2007},
  author = {John Doe},
  address = {Testville},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Postnote spacing/punctuation doesn't work for \verb|\footfullcite|,\footfullcite[1-10]{test}
although everything is correct for \verb|\footcite|.\footcite[1-10]{test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Rather than a link to a ZIP file, it's preferred that the minimal example is spelled out in the question.

Comment: Can you tell more about your setting? What version of biblatex are you using?

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and the bundled biber backend in the newest version (Version: 4689, Date: 11/2/2012).

Comment: That's what I thought. I can try with version 2.2 of biblatex; indeed I'm thinking to a small bug.

Comment: Well do that, hopefully it's somehow solvable!

Comment: It's related to `\finentry`. At some point after 1.7 `\blx@initunit` was uncommented in the definition of `\blx@finentry@usedrv`. Not sure why. Using `\protected\def\blx@finentry@usedrv{\unspace}` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing postnote delimiter is due to a bug in the `\finentry` definition for `\usedriver`. For now add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\blx@finentry@usedrv{\blx@setunit\relax}
\makeatother
```

The above macro has been revised a few times to address problems with whitespace and punctuation. If problems with the new definition arise, please feel free to reopen this issue at the [github repo](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/50).

Comment: @Timm No problem. Thanks for pointing out this issue.